# How to create dropdown list from a timestamp column in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

My column (A) in (Form responses 1) sheet collect the timestamp of the form filling. I need to create a drowdown list in another sheet (Dashboard) that should contain UNIQUE LIST OF MM/YYYY found in that column.

I tried too many solutions:
I tried to create a helping column with this:

1. =Unique(Arrayformula(if(A2:A<>"",month(A2:A)&"/"&YEAR(A2:A),"")))
   And then choose dropdown (From range) the helping column.
2. =UNIQUE(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A<>"", TEXT(A2:A, "mmm yyyy"),"")))
   And then choose dropdown (From range) the helping column.

Also, I tried to:

3. Name ranges (A) or (helping column) and refer to it in the dropdown (From range)

But once I try to select any item from the list, I always get the same error:

There was a problem
The data that you entered in cell B21 violates the data validation rules set on this cell.
please help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your separator is the issue as the value is not text, yet your input is. Instead of using `/` between the month year try an underscore `_` or pretty much anything else.

So try option 1 again, only use this formula:

```
=Unique(Arrayformula(if(A2:A<>"",month(A2:A)&"_"&YEAR(A2:A),"")))
```

Also this is a cleaner function as it won't put some blank values in your initial range (but probably never going to matter) template. Same functional result:

```
=unique(filter(text(A2:A,"YYYY_MM"),ISNUMBER(A2:A)))
```